# How do you retrieve data filled in a form with the submit button?

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to know how to retrieve data from a form people can fill in.

I wrote the form code in HTML with a working submit button.

But now I don't know what to do. I have a javascript file open but what's next?

Comment: You need to set a target file for the form. One way to do this is by using the `action` attribute on the form tag.

Comment: What is your goal? 

Do you want to make something with the data on the page directly or do you want to save data? You need some server side work - for that purposes you need any server. It could be js (like nodejs) or i.e. php server.

For the simple start you could check this simple tutorial - HTML Forms 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: the way you're doing it, the form will initiate an http request with the form content and send it to the `target` attribute of your `<form>` element.